# Google Chrome extensions interaction with Native Client Applications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-nativeclient

Is it possible to write a Chrome Extension that will interact with a Native Client application?

I use Irssi through the NaCl Secure Shell application, and I would like to write an extension that simply looks for plain URLs and makes them clickable links.

I'm seeing some strange behavior with extensions and NaCl applications, so I wanted to know if this is something that is even possible.

Additionally, if anyone has a more elegant solution to this, please don't hesitate to let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the NaCl Secure Shell app uses Native Client under the hood shouldn't matter; the page is rendered using standard HTML.

The documentation for Chrome Extensions [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) says you should be able to inject content scripts into pages with the `chrome-extension` scheme. I tried it, but it doesn't work. It seems the documentation is incorrect. See http://crbug.com/153245.

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to modify an extension this way. It is possible to communicate with other extensions/apps (see [here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#external)), but it seems that the application must expose an API to communicate with.

Answer (score 0):

Secure Shell supports clicking links now via Ctrl+Click.  it will support [OSC+8](https://gist.github.com/egmontkob/eb114294efbcd5adb1944c9f3cb5feda) in a future release.